# .append() returns None

Tags: python, html, jinja2

How could I "silence" that? It strives with the html

```
<h2>Requested,</h2>
<ul>
    <br>
    {% set repetitions = [] %}
    {% for statement in statements if statement.text not in repetitions %}

        <li><p>{{statement.text}}</p></li>
        {{ repetitions.append(statement.text) }}

    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: It seems like you should be doing that *outside* the template.

Comment: Isn't there another way of "appending" that does not return anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can leverage the `do` tag to execute the append, but not print anything.  I was running into issues with the word `repetitions` in my environment, so I changed the variable `repetitions` to `repeated`. I also added a statements variable and printed `repeated` at the end for testing purposes.  Your modified code might be:

**Code:**

```html
{%- set statements = [{'text':'something'},{'text':'something_else'},{'text':'something_else'}] -%}

<h2>Requested,</h2>
<ul>
    <br>
    {%- set repeated = [] -%}
    {% for statement in statements if statement.text not in repeated %}
        <li><p>{{- statement.text -}}</p></li>
        {%- do repeated.append(statement.text) %}
    {%- endfor %}
</ul>

{{ repeated }}
```

**Output:**

```html
<h2>Requested,</h2>
<ul>
    <br>
        <li><p>something</p></li>
        <li><p>something_else</p></li>
</ul>

['something', 'something_else']
```

Source: Jinja Documentation >> Expression Statement https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#expression-statement